# Why does this inverter circuit behave like an amplifier?

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

connect a large value DC bias resistor, to form a CMOS amplifier as shown in the diagram (74HC04 and the 74HCU04 chips)

Comment: At what frequency?

Comment: 74HCU04 isn't really an inverter

Comment: @bobflux how did you know the OP uses 74HCU04?

Comment: Can you ask a more specific question? It works as an amplifier, because a CMOS inverter is basically an amplifier, because at the bias point a small change on input will cause a large change on output. @Bobflux it really is an inverter. So is 4069UB. Datasheets say they are. Datasheets also say they can be used  for analog circuits.

Comment: @Justme I know. I just wanted to ask if "74HCU04" is indicated somewhere.

Comment: @RohatKılıç because the circuit wouldn't make sense with the non-U version

Answer (score 4):

Here's a schematic of a basic, unbuffered CMOS inverter:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9B0q9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The configuration above has already a very high gain because MOSFETs are running as common-source amplifiers with active loads: For example, when the input sees HIGH M1 stays off i.e. basically very high load resistance to M2. So, with large enough feedback resistors, you can decrease the overall gain and force the circuit to run as linear amplifier (without clipping).

Input signal should be AC-coupled, hence the 100n series capacitor.

**EDIT AFTER OP's EDIT:** Chips with "U" have unbuffered output, and those are the ones can work as linear amplifiers. Chips with buffered output (non-U) have a post buffer stage, and this buffer has its input from the previous inverter stage which outputs already-clipped signal *(Actually, the circuit has a few cascade-connected inverters but for the sake of simplicity think of the whole circuit as two-stage)*. Therefore you can't decrease the overall gain and operate the circuit as linear amplifier.

Answer (score 2):

The CMOS-inverter has the following property (assuming a good internal symmetry):

- The transition from "high" to "low" takes place at 50% of the supply voltage Vs.
- The corresponding gate voltage also is Vg=Vs/2.
- When there is a feedback resistor Rf between the output node and the input (gate) we have a fixed operating point (in the middle of the transition region) because this is the only point which can satisfy the condition Vg=Vout=Vs/2.
- Because the operating point is in the middle of the transition region (which can be regarded as quasi-linear in the vicinity of the operating point), we have the possibility to use this (relatively steep) region for amplifying purposes.
- For better linearity (and smaller gain) an additional resistor between the gate node and the input can provide signal feedback. In this case, this circuit works similar to the classical inverting opamp.
- The feedback resistor Rf should have a rather large value (MegOhm range). This is because it acts as a load resistor which - in conjunction with the finite CMOS output resistance - forms a voltage divider thereby reducing the gain. With respect to linearity it is better to realize a higher open-loop gain and to reduce it via negative feedback.